# How to count the number of objects depending on the status?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have the code which counts the number of elements of each type.

Views.py

```
from django.db.models import Count

class HomeView(ListView):
    model = TypeCartridge
    template_name = 'home.html'
    
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        type_counts = TypeCartridge.objects.values('type').annotate(total=Count('type'))
        context['type_counts'] = type_counts
        return context
```

home.html:

```
<div>
  {% for cartridge in object_list %}
        <div>
            <p>Number {{ cartridge.num}}: {{ cartridge.type }}, status {{ cartridge.status }}</p>
        </div>
  {% endfor %}

  <h2>Type Counts</h2>
  <ul>
    {% for type_count in type_counts %}
      <li>{{ type_count.type }} - {{ type_count.total }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

For example, I have a table:

```
num type Status
0000001 Samsung Installed
0000002 Samsung NotInstalled
0000003 Xerox Installed
0000004 Brother NotInstalled
0000005 Brother NotInstalled
0000006 Brother NotInstalled
0000007 HP Installed
0000008 HP Installed
```

And the result of my code is the following:

```
Samsung - 2
Xerox - 1
Brother - 3
HP - 2
```

But I would like the code to count only elements with status "Installed". The result should be
:

```
Samsung - 1
Xerox - 1
HP - 2
```

How to improve the code?

Comment: Just throw a filter in before the `.values()` -> `TypeCartridge.objects.filter(status='Installed').values('type').annotate(total=Count('type'))` ..also 'Installed'?- as a string?? that could be a boolean :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter the table data with status "Installed", which will return entries only with "Installed" status. Then you can count values type wise.

In views.py

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    type_counts = TypeCartridge.objects.filter(status='Installed').values('type').annotate(total=Count('type'))
    context['type_counts'] = type_counts
    return context
```